# Assert image size not working

Tags: eclipse, image, selenium-webdriver, size, assert

I'm testing a responsive website where a different image is used if a browser is reduced in size (or when viewed on a phone). For example, if the browser window is more then 900 wide image is used with dimensions (200, 125). when browser window is between 650 and 899 wide an image used with dimensions (150, 110) and when browser window size / width is lower then 650 an image is used with dimensions (100,75). I'm trying to test this with the following:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
assertEquals("(200, 125)",driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/ul/li[4]/a/div[1]/img")).getSize());
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(899, 750));
assertEquals("(150, 110)",driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/ul/li[4]/a/div[1]/img")).getSize());
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(649, 750));
assertEquals("(100, 75)",driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/ul/li[4]/a/div[1]/img")).getSize());
```

This seems to work but when I run this I get the following message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.String<(200, 125)> but was: org.openqa.selenium.Dimension<(200, 125)>
```

Not sure what this means or how to fix it, the code seems correct.

Using Eclipse with Selenium webdriver and Java.

**Having received the answer below I changed the code to:**

```
assertEquals("(200, 125)",driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/ul/li[4]/a/div[1]/img")).getSize().toString());
```

and allthought that solved the AssertionError and works if the image is that size, resizing the browser causes the image to scale and this I cannot predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm **against** automating visual/layout/rendering checks with Selenium. I see the benefit of UI test automation, but I also appreciate manual testing and value it brings. You expect the image to be of 200x125 size. What it one day it is 199x124? Will the user spot the difference? Probably not. Will your test pass? Probably not.

Secondly, your xpath locators are brittle. If you need to use `/` more than 3 times, you may expect your tests to fail after minor UI refactoring, which may not be noticed by the end user. There aer plenty of good posts on how to create solid xpath locators. You can google for them.

If you still want to automate that, what you need to do is to convert String to Dimension or vice versa. You have type mismatch at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the xpath's used. Not the best ones I've used. As for automating visuals completely, I agree. this is not a smart option. But this can help as a quick test. That said I'd still like to procee but I don't quite understand what you mean with converting string to dimension, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: OK. Figured out how to do it but also found why this does not work. The code that worked (partially) and converts to string: 
assertEquals("(200, 125)",driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/ul/li[4]/a/div[1]/img")).getSize().toString());

The reason this does not work: Allthough the original size is 200, 125 it also scales depening on broswer size and there is no (ease) way to predict the scale (as fas as I know).

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. Now you know why I don't like such checks to be performed by automated tests.